# Constructing a non-commutative ring with $5^9$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

i'm trying to construct a non-commutative ring with $5^9$ elements. Usually in questions like this I do something like start off with $\mathbb{Z_5}[x]$ and then mod out by some degree $9$ (or degree $10?$) irreducible polynomial to get a field with $5^9$ elements. The problem is the question wants it to be non-commutative! and so i am quite lost. Input is appreciated!!

Further more, if anyone could give me some examples of Euclidea rings other $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ i'd appreciate that also!

Comment: Hint: you can’t start with a commutative ring... is there a very standard example of a non-commutative ring that you know of? Say, since linear algebra? And can you do something along those lines?

Comment: Try matrices and $\mathbb Z_5$...

Comment: There are many Euclidean rings; any $F[x]$ is Euclidean, where $F$ is a field, using the degree function. $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the ring of Gaussian integers, is Euclidean (using the square of the norm, $\varphi(a+bi) = a^2+b^2$. Similarly, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Answer (score 3):

In general if $R$ is a ring with $m$ elements, $M_n(R)$ has $m^{n^2}$ elements.

So just use $M_3(\mathbb Z_5)$.

---

There are tons of examples at [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Examples) for Euclidean domains. [Here is the DaRT search](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=113&L=54), whose content may grow over time.

---

For future reference, it is better to ask questions that are completely different from each other in different posts.